# Is there any way to save lots of data on Sharepoint by just using REST api (or any client-side solution)?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-list, client-side-scripting, site-column

I have been asked to develop a web application to be hosted on Sharepoint 2013 that has to work with lots of data. It basically consists in a huge form to be used to save and edit many information.

Unfortunately, due to some work restrictions, I do not have access to the backend, so it has to be done entirely client-side.

I am already aware on how to programmatically create sharepoint lists with site columns and save data on them with REST.
The problem is, I need to create a Sharepoint list (to be used as database) with at least 379 site columns (fields), of which 271 has to be single lines of text and 108 multiple lines of text, and by doing so I think I would exceed the threshold limit (too many site columns on a single list).

Is there any way I could make this work? Any other solution on how to save big amounts of data on Sharepoint, by only using client-side solutions (e.g. REST)? Maybe there is a way to save a XML or JSON file in any way on Sharepoint through REST?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if there is actually some limit regarding columns in SP 2013. For sure there is a limit when You would be using lookup columns (up to 12 columns in one view), but since You are using only text columns this should not be blocking... and limit regarding number of rows that may be present in one view (5000 - normal user, 20 000 - admin user)

Best to check all here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits

As described by MS:

> The sum of all columns in a SharePoint list cannot exceed 8,000 bytes.

Also You may create one Note column and store all date in JSON structure which will be saved in this column or create Library not list and store JSON documents in list (just be aware that by default JSON format is blocked in SharePoint to be stored in lists and You need to change those settings in Central Admin for application pool -> [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3#ID0EAABAAA=2013,_2010)). Just be aware that with this approach You will be not able to use many OOB SharePoint features like column filters which might be handy

Comment: In the link you shared with me there is a section called "column limits", and apparently the maximum number of "single line of text" columns is 255. I don't get though how can a "multiple lines of text" column use less data than a "single line of text" (22 bytes rather than 30 bytes). So, if I use multiple lines of text, I can reach 350 columns, which is anyway less than I need...
By the way, thank you for your tip on storing JSON data in a list, but unfortunately I am not even allowed to modify settings in Central Administration